# Storing a data permanent with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, http, mobile

I am developing an app with Flutter and Firebase.

I want to store the _id with SharedPreferences permanently.

Therefore, i looked after it, but my code doesnt work at all. It always throws the error:

type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Here is my code:

```
class Profile with ChangeNotifier {
  String _id;
  void setName(String name) {
    const url =
        'myurl';
    http
        .post(url, body: json.encode({'name': name, 'description': name}))
        .then((response) {
      _id = json.decode(response.body)['name'];
    });
    addID();
  }

  Future<void> updateName(String name, String id) async {
    String url =
        'myurl';
    await http.patch(url,
        body: json.encode({'name': 'Ein Titel', 'description': name}));
  }
```

And here are my methods with the SharedPrefs:

```
String getID() {
    return getIDOffline();
  }

  addID() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('id', _id);
  }

  getIDOffline() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Return String
    String stringValue = prefs.getString('id');
    return stringValue;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have use wrong method for return string so you have to change `String getID()` to `Future<String> getID()`. And you can use like this.

```
getValue()async{
String value = await getID();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use async always try to add also Future.

like :

```
 Future<returnType> methodName() async { }
```

In your code try to change
`String getID(){ }` to `Future<String>getID() async{ }`